# Laravel Models/function, how to make a main "function"

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

So guy's, I've created a Laravel project.
I have a master. Layout which always contains the user data.
So I have a navbar with $user->name for example.

In every controller I needed to add the User model and also the where function.

```
$user = User::find(auth()->user()->id)
```

Maybe this example is bad, but I've also included the company in the master, so it shows in the Navbar.

Is there a way, that I don't need to repeat that process? So I don't need it always in the controller.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You dont need that, on your blade you can use the `auth()` helper to achieve any data of user. Like , for email `auth()->user()->email`

Comment: just use auth()->user(); it gives you current  user object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In laravel you are extending each class from a main controller so its better to create a method in main class like this

child controller

```
class testController extends Controller
{
   // as you can see its extending so go into Controller class
}
```

parent class, So here i have creatd a getName method here. If you want get the value through mode

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;


class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    private $current_user_name = 'test';

    public function getName()
    {
        return ($this->current_user_name);
    }
}
```

Now go back to child controller and pass this method in view

```
class testController extends Controller
{
       public function index()
      {
        return view('', $data = ['name' => $this->getName()]);
      }
}
```

Hope this cover your query. In this way you don't need to repeat your code in every controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data in your blade template too, like user information, but if you need more complex data and you don't want to put logic in blade, you can use this method (`AppServiceProvider.php`):

```
public function boot()
{
    view()->composer('your_mast_layout', function($view)
    {
        $data = ...
        $view->with('variable_name', $data);
    });
}
```